# Median absolute deviation in Julia

Tags: statistics, geometry, julia, montecarlo, pi

I approximated pi using the Monte Carlo method. 
I am having troubles calculating the Median absolute deviation of my results (see code below). 
My guess is that there is already a function in Julia that does this but unfortunately I have no idea how to implement it in my code.

[image]

```
for i in 1:5
   picircle(1000)
end
```

```
3.0964517741129436
3.152423788105947
3.1284357821089457
3.1404297851074463
3.0904547726136933
```

Comment: there is [`StatsBase.mad`](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/scalarstats/#StatsBase.mad)

Comment: @MarcMush I tried using Statistics but I just can't find the right package to download

Comment: install StatsBase.jl package and then do `using StatsBase`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MarcMush mentioned in the comments, `StatsBase` exports the `mad` function, which as we can see from the docstring

```
help?> mad
search: mad mad! maxad muladd mapreduce meanad ismarked mapfoldr mapfoldl mean_and_var mean_and_std mean_and_cov macroexpand

  mad(x; center=median(x), normalize=true)

  Compute the median absolute deviation (MAD) of collection x around center (by default, around the median).

  If normalize is set to true, the MAD is multiplied by 1 / quantile(Normal(), 3/4) ≈ 1.4826, in order to obtain a consistent
  estimator of the standard deviation under the assumption that the data is normally distributed.
```

so

```
julia> A = randn(10000);

julia> using StatsBase

julia> mad(A, normalize=false)
0.6701649037518176
```

or alternatively, if you don't want the `StatsBase` dependency, then you can just calculate it directly with (e.g.)

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> median(abs.(A .- median(A)))
0.6701649037518176
```

which gives an identical result